# Integrate bootstrap-theme into Ruby on Rails project

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I bought a bootstrap theme,

I wonder How could I integrate it into my Rails project in a good practice

Should I Convert its `Javascript` and `css` into `coffescript` and `scss` separately

If so, It will work when put those files into corresponding folders in Rails project, right ?

My project is based on Rails 4.

Here my project structure

```
├── app
│   ├── assets
│   ├── controllers
│   ├── helpers
│   ├── mailers
│   ├── models
│   └── views
├── bin
│   ├── bundle
│   ├── rails
│   └── rake
├── config
│   ├── application.rb
│   ├── boot.rb
│   ├── database.yml
│   ├── environment.rb
│   ├── environments
│   ├── initializers
│   ├── locales
│   └── routes.rb
├── public
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── 422.html
│   ├── 500.html
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   └── robots.txt
```

This is the folder structure of the theme

It stores `css, javascript, fonts, images`

```
├── css
│   ├── animate.min.css
│   ├── bootstrap.css
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   ├── font-awesome.min.css
│   ├── prettyPhoto.css
│   ├── rs-settings-ie8.css
│   ├── rs-settings.css
│   └── style.css
├── fonts
│   ├── FontAwesome.otf
│   ├── fontawesome-webfont.eot
│   ├── fontawesome-webfont.svg
│   ├── fontawesome-webfont.ttf
│   └── fontawesome-webfont.woff
├── img [23 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
├── index.html
├── js
│   ├── bootstrap.js
│   ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   ├── custom.js
│   ├── gmaps.js
│   ├── html5shiv.js
│   ├── jquery.arbitrary-anchor.js
│   ├── jquery.js
│   ├── jquery.knob.js
│   ├── jquery.prettyPhoto.js
│   ├── jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js
│   ├── jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js
│   ├── respond.min.js
│   └── waypoints.min.js
└── rs-assets [36 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that I know a few ways to perform a good practice:

- 'Gang of Four and Composite pattern' - compose your bootstrap-theme in single monolithic gem.
- Use manifest files to resolve paths.

To *try* second solution:

- put the bootstrap-theme folder into /app/assets directory.
- add to "/bootstrap-theme/js" folder new file, *application.js* with content:

  ```
  //= require_tree .
  ```
- add to "/bootstrap-theme/css" folder new file, *application.css* with content:

  ```
  /*
   *= require_tree .
  */
  ```
- include in  /app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

  ```
  //= require ../bootstrap-theme/js
  ```
- include in  /app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:

  ```
  //= require ../bootstrap-theme/css
  ```